# Format x-axis of highchart: only showing full numbers

Tags: highcharts

I use the highchart "bar with negative stack": http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-negative-stack

I only work with integer numbers, not with floats. My x-Axis looks like this for smaller numbers:

[image]

**My question:**
How can I get rid off the floats and only show full numbers, like so:

[image]

I could not find the related option in the API documentation and also researching did not get me any results.

Answer (score 1):

Set allowDecimals: false , It wont show decimal part. In case of X-axis you can define TickInterval: to an integer value to avoid fractional part

Answer (score 0):

As he said, by putting your tickInterval to whole numbers you can achieve the result.

code :

```
    $(function () {
      $('#container').highcharts({
            xAxis: {
                  tickInterval: 1
                  },
```